# Replace content with information in following rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
tonelabel <- c("H*", "L-", "H*", "L-%", "(L+H*)", "(L*+!H)", "!H*", "H-", "L*", "H-%", "(H*)", "^H*", "H-", "H*", "H-%", "H*", "H-%", "L*", "H-%", "H*", "L-")
boundary <- c("none", "low", "none", "low", "none", "none", "none", "high", "none", "high", "none", "none", "high", "none", "high", "none", "high", "none", "high", "none", "low")
df <- data.frame(tonelabel, boundary) 
df
   tonelabel boundary
1         H*     none
2         L-      low
3         H*     none
4        L-%      low
5     (L+H*)     none
6    (L*+!H)     none
7        !H*     none
8         H-     high
9         L*     none
10       H-%     high
11      (H*)     none
12       ^H*     none
13        H-     high
14        H*     none
15       H-%     high
16        H*     none
17       H-%     high
18        L*     none
19       H-%     high
20        H*     none
21        L-      low
```

In the column df$boundary, the cases called "none" have to be replaced by either "low" or "high". The decision whether it should be "low" or high" must be based on the following "low" or high". So if the next thing following a "none" is a "low", then all the preceeding "none" should become "low". If the next thing is a "high", then all the preceeding "none" should become "high". Always until the next "low" or "high", that is.

Here is what I would like the output to look like:

```
  tonelabel boundary
1         H*      low
2         L-      low
3         H*      low
4        L-%      low
5     (L+H*)     high
6    (L*+!H)     high
7        !H*     high
8         H-     high
9         L*     high
10       H-%     high
11      (H*)     high
12       ^H*     high
13        H-     high
14        H*     high
15       H-%     high
16        H*     high
17       H-%     high
18        L*     high
19       H-%     high
20        H*      low
21        L-      low
```

I can't really think of any solutions as the factor level defining what "none" has to be is following the "none", not preceeding it. So actually, one would have to work from the bottom up. Any ideas would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `zoo` package,

```
df$boundary[df$boundary == 'none'] <- NA

df$boundary <- zoo::na.locf(df$boundary, fromLast = TRUE)
```

Or via `tidyverse`,

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
 mutate(boundary = replace(boundary, boundary == 'none', NA)) %>% 
 fill(boundary, .direction = 'up')
```

Both giving,

> ```
>    tonelabel boundary
> 1         H*      low
> 2         L-      low
> 3         H*      low
> 4        L-%      low
> 5     (L+H*)     high
> 6    (L*+!H)     high
> 7        !H*     high
> 8         H-     high
> 9         L*     high
> 10       H-%     high
> 11      (H*)     high
> 12       ^H*     high
> 13        H-     high
> 14        H*     high
> 15       H-%     high
> 16        H*     high
> 17       H-%     high
> 18        L*     high
> 19       H-%     high
> 20        H*      low
> 21        L-      low
> ```

Comment: Nicely done. I was working on an answer using the `imputeTS` package, but the `dplyr` solution is so much more elegant that I won't even bother posting.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza I never heard that package. Maybe I ll take the tour

Comment: I recommend it. The package does one thing but does it well.

Comment: @AndrewBrēza You should post your answer and expose us to that package.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sotos !! The zoo package solution works like a charm. The tidyverse also works, but I had trouble "saving" the results into my dataframe rather than just displaying them. I don't really know the syntax here, but the usual df<- or df$boundary<- didn't seem to work.

Comment: Never mind, I worked it out myself :) it helps to put df<- aaaall the way in front of the tidyverse code. ;)